# Spoofing postMethod (apache in java)?

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

Im fairly new to this so please dont slam me down.

I'm trying to mock a Postmethod so that I can set the status it returns. For instance I want to set my PostMethod to 200.

The reason for doing this is I am trying to mock a computer without an internet connection

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What mocking library are you using? The syntax will vary.

In [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), for example, you might do the following:

```
final PostMethod mockPostMethod = Mockito.mock(PostMethod.class);
when(mockPostMethod.execute(Mockito.any(HttpState.class),
    Mockito.any(HttpConnection.class))).thenReturn(200);
```

And of course you could use a static import of the Mockito class to avoid the extra qualified references.